# Custom Electron Titlebar when not using index.html

Tags: javascript, electron, titlebar

When using the following code:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(`http://www.google.com/`);
```

I am not able to make a custom titlebar with css/html as i am not using an index.html as i would be able to if i was using this code:

```
loaderWindow.loadURL(`file:///${__dirname}/loader.html`);
```

Ive tried custom npm packages like electron-titlebar-windows & custom-electron-titlebar. Nothing seems to work when im displaying an external page from loadURL.

Here is my current implementation of custom-electron-titlebar, in the renderer process:

```
let MyTitleBar = new customTitlebar.Titlebar({
  backgroundColor: customTitlebar.Color.fromHex('#03a9f4')
});

MyTitleBar.updateTitle('Test Title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `setTitle` [Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsettitletitle)

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  mainWindow.setTitle('Test Title');
});
```

Comment: the problem with this method is that i cant set the color...which is sort of what im after. the ideal way would be to style the titlebar with css just like you could if you were to specify an index.html.

Comment: What about just iframing the page you can't control?

Comment: iframe adds garbage borders that i cant get rid of.

Comment: @IgnitionK6 You can remove that with `frameBorder`  `<iframe frameBorder="0"></iframe>`

Comment: incredibly useful information. cant believe i didnt think of that. i do have one additional problem though...for authorization through my app, i cant really use iframe. UX wise, its perfect, however from a functional standpoint its best to use window.loadurl. Is there any solution to change the titlebar styling without using iframe?

Comment: If you do not control the html, you cannot fully control the title bar.